# What about this mess? Ideas to better rewrite it?

Tags: python

This mess is working well, but if somebody has any ideas to make it look/perform better, it would be greatly appreciated!

```
def OnButtonClick(b, e, f="none"):
    if b == Gui["goleft"]   and e == viz.UP: do_Cam([1.475, 7.862, 10.293])
    if b == Gui["gocenter"] and e == viz.UP: do_Cam([0, 1, 52])
    if b == Gui["goright"]  and e == viz.UP: do_Cam([0, 11, 5])
    if b == Gui["godown"]   and e == viz.UP: do_Cam([0, 16, 53])

def OnSliders(POS, S):
    if S == 1:
        Gui["bars_alpha"].message(str('%.2f'%(POS)))
        CFG["BAR_alpha"] = POS
        for i in BAR_Items: BAR_Items[i].alpha(POS)
    elif S == 2:
        Gui["shps_alpha"].message(str('%.2f'%(POS)))
        CFG["SHP_alpha"] = POS
        for i in ISOS.keys(): SHAPE[i+"_SHP"].alpha(POS)
    elif S == 3:
        Gui["bars_sizes"].message(str('%.2f'%(POS)))
        CFG["BAR_scale"] = [POS, 0.15, POS]
        for i in BAR_Items: BAR_Items[i].scale(POS, BAR_Items[i].getScale()[1], POS)
    elif S == 4:
        Gui["label_alpha"].message(str('%.2f'%(POS)))
        CFG["BARTXT_alpha"] = POS
        for i in BAR_Label: BAR_Label[i].alpha(POS)
    elif S == 5:
        Gui["label_size"].message(str('%.2f'%(POS)))
        CFG["BARTXT_scale"] = [POS, POS, POS]
        for i in BAR_Label: BAR_Label[i].scale(POS, POS, POS)
    elif S == 6:
        Gui["grid_alpha"].message(str('%.2f'%(POS)))
        CFG["grid_alpha"] = POS
        [Griditema[i].alpha(POS) for i in Griditema]
        [Griditemb[i].alpha(POS) for i in Griditemb]
```

After following some of the initial recommendations I received, I now have:

```
def OnButtonClick(b, e, f="none"):
    if e != viz.UP: return
    if b == Gui["goleft"]   : do_Cam([1.475, 7.862, 10.293])
    elif b == Gui["gocenter"] : do_Cam([0, 1, 5])
    elif b == Gui["goright"]  : do_Cam([0, 1, 5])
    elif b == Gui["godown"]   : do_Cam([0, 1, 5])

def OnSliders(POS, S):
    if S == 1:
        CFG["BAR_alpha"] = POS
        for i in BAR_Items: BAR_Items[i].alpha(POS)
    elif S == 2:
        CFG["SHP_alpha"] = POS
        for i in ISOS.keys(): SHAPE[i+"_SHP"].alpha(POS)
    elif S == 3:
        CFG["BAR_scale"] = [POS, 0.15, POS]
        for i in BAR_Items: BAR_Items[i].scale(POS, BAR_Items[i].getScale()[1], POS)
    elif S == 4:
        CFG["BARTXT_alpha"] = POS
        for i in BAR_Label: BAR_Label[i].alpha(POS)
    elif S == 5:
        CFG["BARTXT_scale"] = [POS, POS, POS]
        for i in BAR_Label: BAR_Label[i].scale(POS, POS, POS)
    elif S == 6:
        CFG["grid_alpha"] = POS
        for i in Griditema: Griditema[i].alpha(POS)
        for i in Griditemb: Griditemb[i].alpha(POS)

    mydict  = {1:"bars_alpha", 2:"shps_alpha", 3:"bars_sizes", 4:"label_alpha", 5:"label_size", 6:"grid_alpha"}
    Gui[mydict[S]].message('%.2f' % POS)
```

This is how it ended:

```
def OnButtonClick(b, e, f="none"):
    if e != viz.UP: return
    if b == Gui["goleft"]    : do_Cam([1.475, 7.862, 10.293])
    elif b == Gui["gocenter"]: do_Cam([0, 1, 5])
    elif b == Gui["goright"] : do_Cam([0, 1, 5])
    elif b == Gui["godown"]  : do_Cam([0, 1, 5])

def OnSliders(POS, S):
    D = {1:"BAR_alpha", 2:"SHP_alpha", 3:"BAR_scale", 4:"TXT_alpha", 5:"TXT_scale", 6:"grid_alpha"}
    if   S == 1: CFG[D[S]] = POS; [BAR_Items[i].alpha(POS) for i in BAR_Items]
    elif S == 2: CFG[D[S]] = POS; [SHAPE[i+"_SHP"].alpha(POS) for i in ISOS.keys()] 
    elif S == 3: CFG[D[S]] = [POS, 0.15, POS]; [BAR_Items[i].scale(POS, BAR_Items[i].getScale()[1], POS) for i in BAR_Items]
    elif S == 4: CFG[D[S]] = POS; [BAR_Label[i].alpha(POS) for i in BAR_Label]
    elif S == 5: CFG[D[S]] = [POS, POS, POS]; [BAR_Label[i].scale(POS, POS, POS) for i in BAR_Label]
    elif S == 6: CFG[D[S]] = POS; [Griditema[i].alpha(POS) for i in Griditema]; [Griditemb[i].alpha(POS) for i in Griditemb]
    Gui[D[S]].message('%.2f' % POS)
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would follow Preet Sangha's advice with these additional improvements.

Replace

```
str('%.2f'%(POS))
```

with

```
'%.2f' % POS
```

I think it is a bad practice to use list comprehension to produce side effects.

```
[Griditema[i].alpha(POS) for i in Griditema]
```

Assuming Griditema is a dict.

```
for item in Griditema.itervalues():
   item.alpha(POS)
```

Comment: my guess is that `Griditema` is a dict of some sort. So it would simplify to `for item in Griditema.values(): item.alpha(POS)`

Answer (score 2):

First thing I would do it replace the repeated code with functions..
such as

```
Gui["bars_alpha"].message(str('%.2f'%(POS)))
CFG["BAR_alpha"] = POS
```

with

```
def DoIt(pos): 
  Gui[pos].message(str('%.2f'%(POS)))
  CFG[pos] = POS
```

Then I'd replace the big if/else with a dictionary of llamdas

Answer (score 1):

You could replace the first line of each case with a single array lookup (`Gui[keys[S]]...`), but frankly I don't think there's much to be gained. The code does look complex, but the complexity is real, not just an artefact of how you coded it.

Answer (score 1):

```
def OnButtonClick(b, e, f="none"):
    if e != viz.UP: return
    if b == Gui["goleft"]: do_Cam([1.475, 7.862, 10.293])
    if b == Gui["gocenter"]: do_Cam([0, 1, 52])
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that mess is derived by others mess in the design of the application.
My suspicion is that you don't have any action object for all of those actions.